# Easy login script without database

Tags: php, authentication

How do I create an easy login script that does not require a database. I would like it to be safe.

Alright, what about this script, i just made it by my knowledge in php.

```
<?php 
// Start session
session_start(); 

// Username and password
$ID = "admin";
$pass = "123456";

if (isset($_POST["ID"]) && isset($_POST["pass"])) { 

    if ($_POST["ID"] === $anvandarID && $_POST["pass"] === $pass) { 
    /
    $_SESSION["inloggedin"] = true; 

    header("Location: safe_site.php"); 
    exit; 
    } 
        // Wrong login - message
        else {$wrong = "Bad ID and password, the system could not log you in";} 
}
?>
```

The safe_site.php contains this and some content:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["inloggning"]) || $_SESSION["inloggning"] !== true) {
header("Location: login.php");
exit;
}
```

Comment: How would you create an easy login script that does not require a database in ASP?

Comment: Now what about my example i added in first post above here.

Comment: @Elijah: You want all users to use the same username/password?

Comment: No, not quite really, but now i saw that Mark posted a quick and dirty solution and i use it now! Thanks everybody for your help, i appreciate your time.

Comment: @Elijah: The solution Mark provided is fine if you only one small list of users. That solution won't scale very well.

Comment: @Jonathan  Agreed.  My solution would only be reasonable as a quick wrapper around a VERY small number of pages with not very many users.  Anything with lots of users or user info that changes often would need something more robust.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402782/password-protect-a-page-without-db-access-with-php)

and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286938/what-is-the-best-way-to-password-protect-folder-page-using-php-without-a-db-or-u)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's not an ideal solution but here's a quick and dirty example that shows how you could store login info in the PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();

$userinfo = array(
                'user1'=>'password1',
                'user2'=>'password2'
                );

if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = '';
    header('Location:  ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    if($userinfo[$_POST['username']] == $_POST['password']) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    }else {
        //Invalid Login
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if($_SESSION['username']): ?>
            <p>You are logged in as <?=$_SESSION['username']?></p>
            <p><a href="?logout=1">Logout</a></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <form name="login" action="" method="post">
            Username:  <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
            Password:  <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's maybe better than mine.

Comment: Storing passwords in plain text is generally considered to be unsafe.

Comment: The only way anyone is going to see those passwords is if the web server stops parsing PHP.  And then you'll have a larger problem on your hands :)  He's just looking for something quick and easy.

Comment: Server doesn't have to stop parsing PHP, when there is other vulnerability in application (there is always at least one :) ), than the attacker will be able to read other people passwords without anybody knowing and that is a large problem as you said. Few sha1 function calls won't kill anybody and it'll be safer.

Answer (score 11):

<strike>[FacebookConnect](http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php)</strike> or [OpenID](http://openid.net/) are two great options.

Basically, your users login to other sites they are already members of (Facebook, or Google), and then you get confirmation from that site telling you the user is trustworthy - start a session, and they're logged in. No database needed (unless you want to associate more data to their account).

Comment: The https://developers.facebook.com/connect.php URL now shows *"Sorry, the link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed."* - it should be removed.

Answer (score 8):

I would use a two file setup like this:

index.php

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

define('DS',  TRUE); // used to protect includes
define('USERNAME', $_SESSION['username']);
define('SELF',  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );

if (!USERNAME or isset($_GET['logout']))
 include('login.php');

// everything below will show after correct login 
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php defined('DS') OR die('No direct access allowed.');

$users = array(
 "user" => "userpass"
);

if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = '';
    header('Location:  ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    if($users[$_POST['username']] !== NULL && $users[$_POST['username']] == $_POST['password']) {
  $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
  header('Location:  ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }else {
        //invalid login
  echo "<p>error logging in</p>";
    }
}

echo '<form method="post" action="'.SELF.'">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <p><label for="username">Username</label> <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" /></p>
  <p><label for="password">Password</label> <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" /></p>
  <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button"/></p>
  </form>';
exit; 
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Save the username and password hashes in array in a php file instead of db.

When you need to authenticate the user, compute hashes of his credentials and then compare them to hashes in array.

If you use safe hash function (see [hash function and hash algos](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.hash.php) in PHP documentation), it should be pretty safe (you may consider using salted hash) and also add some protections to the form itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a database, where will the PERMANENT record of your users' login data be stored?  Sure, while the user is logged in, the minimal user information required for your site to work can be stored in a session or cookie.  But after they log out, then what?  The session goes away, the cookie can be hacked.

So your user comes back to your site.  He tries to log in.  What trustworthy thing does your site compare his login info to?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
        session_start();
        $userinfo = array(
            'user'=>'5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592', //Hello...
        );

        if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = '';
            header('Location:  ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        }

        if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
            if($userinfo[$_POST['username']] == md5($_POST['password'])) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            }else {
                header("location:403.html"); //replace with 403
            }
        }
?>
<?php if($_SESSION['username']): ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Logged In</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <p>You're logged in.</p>
            <a href="logout.php">LOG OUT</a>
        </body>
    </html>

<?php else: ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Log In</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Login needed</h1>
            <form name="login" action="" method="post">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"><strong>System Login</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="78">Username:</td>
                        <td width="294"><input name="username" type="text" id="username"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password:</td>
                        <td><input name="password" type="password" id="password"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You will need a logout, something like this (logout.php):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header("location:index.html"); //Replace with Logged Out page. Remove if you want to use HTML in same file.
?>

// Below is not needed, unless header above is missing. In that case, put logged out text here.
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Put logged out message here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Frank, nice answer - however the question had been answered and the answer was accepted.  If you want to explain why your answer is different or better than the accepted answer, that might help.

Answer (score 1):

***LOGIN script that doesnt link to a database or external file. Good for a global password -

Place on Login form page - place this at the top of the login page - above everything else***

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Login'])){

if(strtolower($_POST["username"])=="ChangeThis" && $_POST["password"]=="ChangeThis"){
session_start();
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;
header("Location: ./YourPageAfterLogin.php");

}else {
$error= "Login failed !";
}
}
//print"version3<br>";
//print"username=".$_POST["username"]."<br>";
//print"password=".$_POST["username"];
?>
```

***Login on following pages - Place this at the top of every page that needs to be protected by login. this checks the session and if a user name and password has  ***

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) OR $_SESSION['logged_in'] != TRUE){

header("Location: ./YourLoginPage.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Isn't this solution the same as what's already in the original question?

Answer (score 0):

if you dont have a database, you will have to hardcode the login details in your code, or read it from a flat file on disk.

Comment: Can't I store login details in variables?

Comment: You can, that's what he means by "hardcode the login details in your code."

Answer (score 0):

You can do the access control at the Web server level using HTTP Basic authentication and [htpasswd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html). There are a number of problems with this:

1. It's not very secure (username and password are trivially encoded on the wire)
2. It's difficult to maintain (you have to log into the server to add or remove users)
3. You have no control over the login dialog box presented by the browser
4. There is no way of logging out, short of restarting the browser.

Unless you're building a site for internal use with few users, I wouldn't really recommend it.

Answer (score -4):

There's no reason for not using database for login implementation, the very least you can do is to download and install SQLite if your hosting company does not provide you with enough DB.