# PHP Include an Array

Tags: php, arrays, include

I am creating a flat file login system for a client (as their IT team does not want to give us a database)

I have worked off this:[Easy login script without database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381205/easy-login-script-without-database) which works perfect however...

I need to add a large list of logins and wanted to include them in a septrate file rather than in that script.

I have something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

// this replaces the array area of the link above
includes('users.php');

//and some more stuff

?>
```

And in the users file I have

```
$userinfo = array(
                'kate'=>'inciterocks!',
                'nick'=>'inciterocks!'
                );
```

However it just literally outputs the text from that file. Is there a way I can include it so it just runs like it was in the main script?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement name is actually [`include`](http://php.net/include), and not `includes`.

Try the following:

```
include 'users.php';
```

And if your code is getting outputted as text, then it's probably because you've missed the opening `<?php` tags. Make sure they're present.

`users.php` should look something like this:

```
<?php

$userinfo = array(
                'kate'=>'inciterocks!',
                'nick'=>'inciterocks!'
                );
```

However, the closing tag is not a requirement and your code will work fine without it.

Comment: you're right about the spelling, but a bit wrong about `include` itself. this is **not a function** but a statement (so you can throw away the senseless parenthese)

Answer (score 3):

Include in PHP works simply like a reference to other piece of code AND any other content. So you should enclose the contents of the file in the `<?php` tags so it would be parsed as PHP.

You may as well return anything from an included file (I mention this as this in your case is the best solution):

mainfile.php

```
<?php
session_start();

// this replaces the array area of the link above
$userinfo = include('users.php');
```

users.php

```
return array(
    'kate'=>'inciterocks!',
    'nick'=>'inciterocks!'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Yii framework (configs for exmaple) it's done like this

```
$users = include('users.php');
```

users.php:

```
<?php
 return array(
       'user1' => array(...), 
       'user2' => array(...),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an opening PHP tag in the included file:

```
<?php
    $userinfo = array(
        'kate'=>'inciterocks!',
        'nick'=>'inciterocks!'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

**users.php :**

```
<?php
function getUsers(){
    return array(
       'user1' => array(...), 
       'user2' => array(...),
    );
}
```

**Some bootstrap file**

```
include('users.php');
$myUsers = getUsers();
```

Comment: While the code might work, please always indicate what and why you think this the solution. Provide a bigger context give everyone the understanding why this is the solution for the problem.