# Checkbox gets unchecked after refresh in google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, checkbox

My website has a search box. If you search a term, it will give results. The results page have a checkbox to filter the results.

When I click on the checkbox, the result page gets refreshed to give the filtered results.
I get the filtered results but the checkbox gets unchecked in google chrome.

The same checkbox remains checked if I use firefox or IE(all versions).

I want the checkbox to remain checked so that user knows that the checkbox was checked to filter out result.

It would be preferable if javascript can be used to solve this issue.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Try using cookies or localStorage

Comment: Hi Arvind, Thanks for the response but I cannot use cookies or localStorage due to some restrictions.

Comment: do you know php? use session instead

Comment: @Pratik, in that case if you still wana go for client side solution, you may go with query string, same thing is used by many search engines e.g. [Search Pratik](https://www.google.com/search?q=Pratik)

Comment: I am using struts java and jsp.

Answer (score -1):

You should use Session, as CodeSlayer said. Take a look at this link: [Create a simple PHP login with sessions and multiple users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23631184/create-a-simple-php-login-with-sessions-and-multiple-users) 
Create a session variable that is 1 if the checkbox is checked, 0 otherwise and verify at the beginning of the page what is the state of the checkbox and check it accordingly. For needing more information about how to do this ask.