# Insert unique code to download file

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

I would like to make a page where you insert a unique code it links you to a specific file for that code. Something like this website. http://animalstylerecords.com/downloads/

Comment: so make it. what's the question?

Comment: And you want us to write this site for you?

Comment: The solution is not complicated. What have you tried now?

Comment: The question is how do you do it? I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: @user1081025 please reads the faq, before asking questions on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @user1081025 "I have no idea what I'm doing.". That comment made me laugh a lot. I thought the same way when the preacher asked me if I wanted to marry my fiancée

Comment: Simple: hardcode a series of `if` tests. Better: use a [database] to map codes to destinations.

Answer (score 2):

A few pointers:

- store the files somewhere outside the web root, where people can't simple download them by guessing the URL; see [How do I prevent public downloads of files using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339649/how-do-i-prevent-public-downloads-of-files-using-php)
- somehow map codes to file names; this could be a simple array or a whole database, depending on your needs
- confirm that a code is valid and output the requested file using [`readfile`](http://www.php.net/readfile), look at the example on the manual page