# Getting a discussion forum /query support on my website

Tags: php, forum

I want to have a forum like thing on my website.I dont want any complicated thing, just the user must be able to post questions and the administrator(that is me) can answer them..(It would be nice if it has tree like structure but even without that it is fine) ..All the users can read the questions on the forum anytime(obvious) ..I dont want to put phpbb3 or any such readymade tool..I just want to be it simple (something like [this](http://www.codechef.com/JULY12/problems/LEBOBBLE) scroll to the bottom) ..How to get this thing done..If possible in php please tell that..Otherwise tell other options..Please help me out..

Comment: A comments system? Just use [Disqus](http://disqus.com/) or something like it

Comment: @esqew :Yes I need a disqus system only but the problem is that the webpage will be opertated in LAN not internet

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do something like this in WordPress. (Your local webserver would need to be running MySQL as well as PHP to achieve this.) At the simplest level you could set up a page and allow user comments on it.

Comment: Yes thats what my first thought was.But I want the user to only ask question.Answers to that would be given my me only..

Comment: Just use the moderation tools to remove inappropriate content. (You may want to moderate all comments by default and only allow the ones you want.)

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way is just to have a basic form with text-input, textarea, and submit button. Then have the person input their name, question, and submit it. Make sure you validate the form with js and/or php. Then update a [password protected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286938/what-is-the-best-way-to-password-protect-folder-page-using-php-without-a-db-or-u) page that only you can access with the name and question. Then using whatever cms you have for this page (or just static html if you have the patience) you can just update the front page with the new question and answer above the form.

The best way, though, is going to be some kind of "readymade" system that you tweak...

Comment: Can u be a bit more detailed with the without email part since my school has LAN but no internet