# Using multiple passwords for a simple password-protected page

Tags: php, html, forms, passwords, password-protection

I am trying to protect some pages in my website using PHP, but without creating a database or a username.

I was following the instructions written on a comment on this post: [What is the best way to password protect folder/page using php without a db or username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286938/what-is-the-best-way-to-password-protect-folder-page-using-php-without-a-db-or-u)
Which works great! But I would like to go one step further and change the code so to accept multiple passwords on the same page. Is this possible?

I imagine it would be something like : check if the value retrieved exists on the $password array

```
//access.php

<?php
//put sha1() encrypted password here - example is 'hello'
$password = 'aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d';

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
   $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = false;
}

if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
  if (sha1($_POST['password']) == $password) {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
  } else {
     die ('Incorrect password');
  }
} 

if (!$_SESSION['loggedIn']): ?>

<html><head><title>Login</title></head>
<body>
 <p>You need to login</p>
 <form method="post">
  Password: <input type="password" name="password"> <br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
```

```
<?php
exit();
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of passwords, then use the in_array function to check if the users password is in there.

The lines to change are:

```
$passwords = array("aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d", "aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d", "etc..");
```

and

```
if (in_array(sha1($_POST['password']), $passwords)) {
```

Comment: You nailed it Tom! Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set your passwords as an array and loop trough to check them like this

```
$passwords = [
    'aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d',
    'aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d',
    'aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d',
];


if (isset($_POST['password'])) {

  $result = false;

  foreach($passwords as $password){
      if (sha1($_POST['password']) == $password) {
        $result = true;
     }
  }

  if($result) {
     $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
  } else {
     die ('Incorrect password');
  }

}
```