# Password protecting a webpage with PHP

Tags: php, html, web

I've tried to password protect my website with Tom's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286938/what-is-the-best-way-to-password-protect-folder-page-using-php-without-a-db-or-u). I have copied his access.php script only changing the 5th line to:

```
$password = 'hello';
```

I've then created another file ('test.php') in the same directory on the server, and added the following to it:

```
<?php
require('access.php');
?>
secret text
```

However when I type in 'hello' on [my site](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~oangelil/test/test.php), it tells me my password is incorrect. Is there something about the way the server has been setup that would not allow this? Although I have tried this on two different servers that have both been setup for html and php, and in both cases my password is not accepted.

Comment: His password is hashed. Yours isn't. Check the comment in the line before the password: _"//put sha1() encrypted password here - example is 'hello'"_. You have to put the result `sha1('hello')` in there.

Comment: i would seriously consider user validation using FB, OpenID and/or Google+.  If you need help with that, just holler and i'll walk you thru the process.  100% safe AND you are not liable for damages caused from leaked info because you never even see the user's password anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the 5th line to "hello" cause the provided code **aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d** already means "hello" after the sha1 process of encripting security. Or: maintain the code provided and you will see "hello" working.

Comment: You could suggest the op to change the code to `$password = sha1('NEW_PASS_HERE');`

Comment: spot on.  if you insist on doing password verification yourself, this is the way to do it.