# Password protect automatically generated .html files

Tags: php, html

I'm using the code in Tom's response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286938/what-is-the-best-way-to-password-protect-folder-page-using-php-without-a-db-or-u). However I have a script that automatically generates .html files into my public_html folder. These files are then loaded by my .php file, which looks something like this:

```
<?php
require('./access.php');
include('./secret_information.html');
?>
```

However the "secret_information.html" file is viewable by anyone without the password. I am running an Apache web server. As I understand, all html code / images to be used on a website need to be in the public_html folder. So how can I hide this information? Do I need to setup my automated scripts to generate .php files rather than .html or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) can access any file, as long as it is accessible by the web server.

So you can put secret_information.html anywhere in the file system, *preferably* outside of the document root or `public_html`.

If you must keep the file inside your publicly accessible web for some reason, you may use Apache's [Authentication and Authorization](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html) facility.

Comment: Thank you! Files outside public_html are not accessible by the web server. I suppose I'll have to use Apache's Authentication and Authorization facility.